# Easy fix for LibreOffice Impress font problems on Lubutu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice, fonts, 20.04

I'm hesitant to ask this problem here because it might be considered cross-posting. However, I need to decide whether to downgrade from Lubuntu 20.04 to 18.04.

There is a [bug with LibreOffice Impress](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=132319) where slides will have text squished together to the point of being unreadable.

[image: Slide with squished text]

The slides are fine on Ubuntu 18.04 and also on Lubuntu 18.04. However, after upgrading a lightweight laptop from Lubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 now I have this problem. The only purpose of this laptop is for presentations so it's a pretty big deal.

The bug was posted on LibreOffice's Bugzilla two weeks ago and there has been no forward movement on it. So, I realize that will take time.

My question is, is there anyone who has seen this or has **some idea on how it can be fixed, perhaps some workaround** so I don't need to install Lubuntu 18.04 again?

Comment: One alternative could be to uninstall LibreOffice completely and then install the version that works for you: https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about the default packaged version, have you tried the `snap` version (6.4.3.2).  https://snapcraft.io/libreoffice   (*I don't know if it has your issue, but it's what I'd try first*).

Comment: @DKBose So you mean just downgrade LibreOffice point by point until I (hopefully) find a version that works on Lubuntu 20.04? If that amount of work is needed, it would be far less trouble just to reinstall Lubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Maybe there are some missing fonts in the upgraded version and it ries to emulate them without success. If you install the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` you will get a lot of nice fonts (and also a lot of software to play multimedia).

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for the idea. I'll try that. The font is Liberation Sans (slides were created on Ubuntu) so there should not be a problem but still, it's easy to try.

Comment: I checked in my fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and Liberation Sans is rendered correctly for me. I think there is some cruft (some data from the previous version) that is disturbing the settings of LibreOffice. So try to **purge** it (not only re-install), `sudo apt purge libreoffice` and then install it. Let us hope you will get rid of the cruft that way.

Comment: @sudodus Strangely, running that command says that libreoffice is not installed (but clearly it is). `whereis libreoffice` shows it is under `/usr/bin/libreoffice` Any ideas how to unstall libreoffice from Lubuntu? Even if I install Ubuntu Software Center, it says LO is not installed (so, not helpful to remove it).

Comment: @sudodus Installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` did not help.

Comment: What is the output from `apt-cache policy libreoffice` ?

Comment: @sudodus Installed: (none)  Candidate: 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3. However, I just learned about Muon (the package manager for Lubutu). Even that says that LO is not installed (but it is).

Comment: Yes, I got that result too, which is confusing, but `apt` seems to see Impress, so what is the output from `apt-cache policy libreoffice-impress`? Maybe you can purge an reinstall that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107572/discussion-between-sudodus-and-john).

Comment: @guiverc Your comment was actually the solution. If you write it up as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user @sudodus helped out the OP in chat, so thank you @sudodus

I have seen numerous bugs reported on launchpad since 20.04's launch which are being fixed by LibreOffice upstream, but I didn't look to see if this was one. The OP had reported the issue was gone once the snap version was installed, so to install it just enter

`sudo snap install libreoffice`

[image]

This will result in two versions of LibreOffice installed (original *deb* and new *snap* version).

Should you want to remove the originally supplied version it consists of these packages

- libreoffice-calc
- libreoffice-impress
- libreoffice-writer
- libreoffice-base-core
- libreoffice-gtk3
- libreoffice-qt5
- libreoffice-style-breeze
- libreoffice-draw
- libreoffice-math
- and some libs etc

Those can be removed with

```
sudo apt remove libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-impress
sudo apt remove libreoffice-core libreoffice-common
sudo apt remove libreoffice-style-breeze
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: I tested the removal of packages anyway... the `snap install` was taking awhile to download, and I aborted that..

Comment: I still cannot remove the outer shell of libreoffice (installed by default in Lubuntu). Every other component is gone but the overall app is there. When I try `sudo apt remove libreoffice-base-core` it says `Package 'libreoffice-base-core' is not installed, so not removed`  Can I manually delete it (safely)?

Comment: My test of removal packages was based on a almost new install of Lubuntu (a QA-test install pre-release that I may have used for other support issues, I modify its wallpaper to reflect changes which has now been modified to course).  I'd used a few commands (apt remove but not hitting "y" to proceed) and that was the smallest to remove what i wanted given what I saw in package dependencies).  If you'd removed some already that would mean your needed commands could change.  You could use `dpkg -l |grep "ii  libre"` to list what's still installed. Let me know if you need help

Comment: It did not return anything at all. As this has been a bit involved, I have created a new [question for it here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1235929/551485).

Comment: Sorry, I use other boxes for testing (this is now 20.10 anyway on my primary box) & hand-type the commands used into answers here when I'm happy, so my actual commands were hopefully as now listed above (except I ran `sudo apt autoremove` after each) . I missed the later two *very relevant*  commands I'd when I created this answer. Sorry for missing those packages in the 'answer' as originally written.  All packages could be written on the same `apt remove` line of course..

Answer (score 0):

Comment `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN` in the `/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu/lxqt/session.conf` file.

Solution from: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1881364